# Using a permutation table to fill in gaps

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, permutation

I have a table of permutations that I expect to exist. Then I have a table of actual data. I am trying to join the permutation table in such a way that all permutations exist and if actual data exists then the VALUE is what it was, otherwise its null.

```
CREATE TABLE Data
    ([ID] int, [NAME] varchar(8), [FACTOR_VALUE] numeric, [CLASS] int)
;

INSERT INTO Data
    ([ID], [NAME], [FACTOR_VALUE], [CLASS])
VALUES
    (1, 'FLEX_AVG', 12.1, 2),
    (1, 'FLEX_AVG', 34.4, 1),
    (2, 'FLEX_AVG', 22.1, 1)
;

CREATE TABLE Permutations
    ([CLASS] int, [NAME] varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO Permutations
    ([CLASS], [NAME])
VALUES
    (1, 'FLEX_AVG'),
    (2, 'FLEX_AVG'),
    (3, 'FLEX_AVG'),
    (1, 'RIGID_AVG'),
    (2, 'RIGID_AVG'),
    (3, 'RIGID_AVG')
;
```

This is my attempt:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    X.ID,
    A.NAME,
    IIF(X.Class = A.Class AND X.NAME = A.NAME, FACTOR_VALUE, NULL) AS FACTOR_VALUE,
    A.CLASS
FROM Data X
LEFT JOIN Permutations A
ON 1=1
```

But this yields:

```
ID  NAME    FACTOR_VALUE    CLASS
1   FLEX_AVG    NULL    1
1   FLEX_AVG    NULL    2
1   FLEX_AVG    NULL    3
1   FLEX_AVG    12.1    2
1   FLEX_AVG    34.4    1
1   RIGID_AVG   NULL    1
1   RIGID_AVG   NULL    2
1   RIGID_AVG   NULL    3
2   FLEX_AVG    NULL    2
2   FLEX_AVG    NULL    3
2   FLEX_AVG    22.1    1
2   RIGID_AVG   NULL    1
2   RIGID_AVG   NULL    2
2   RIGID_AVG   NULL    3
```

and I am after:

```
ID  NAME    FACTOR_VALUE    CLASS
1   FLEX_AVG    NULL    3
1   FLEX_AVG    12.1    2
1   FLEX_AVG    34.4    1
1   RIGID_AVG   NULL    1
1   RIGID_AVG   NULL    2
1   RIGID_AVG   NULL    3
2   FLEX_AVG    NULL    2
2   FLEX_AVG    NULL    3
2   FLEX_AVG    22.1    1
2   RIGID_AVG   NULL    1
2   RIGID_AVG   NULL    2
2   RIGID_AVG   NULL    3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cross joining the distinct `id` from your `Data` table with your `Permutations` table gives you combinations you want, and the `left join` to `Data` populates the corresponding values.

```
select 
    A.id,
    A.name,
    X.factor_value,
    A.class
from (
  select distinct
      a.*
    , d.id 
  from Permutations A 
    cross join Data D
    ) as A
  left join Data X
    on a.Name = x.Name 
   and a.Class = x.Class
   and a.Id = x.Id
```

---

This can also be written with a simpler subquery:

```
select 
    D.id,
    A.name,
    X.factor_value,
    A.class
from Permutations A 
  cross join (select distinct id from Data) D
  left join Data X
    on a.Name = x.Name 
   and a.Class = x.Class
   and d.Id = x.Id
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/EJJI30111

returns:

```
+----+-----------+--------------+-------+
| id |   name    | factor_value | class |
+----+-----------+--------------+-------+
|  1 | FLEX_AVG  | 34,40        |     1 |
|  2 | FLEX_AVG  | 22,10        |     1 |
|  1 | RIGID_AVG | NULL         |     1 |
|  2 | RIGID_AVG | NULL         |     1 |
|  1 | FLEX_AVG  | 12,10        |     2 |
|  2 | FLEX_AVG  | NULL         |     2 |
|  1 | RIGID_AVG | NULL         |     2 |
|  2 | RIGID_AVG | NULL         |     2 |
|  1 | FLEX_AVG  | NULL         |     3 |
|  2 | FLEX_AVG  | NULL         |     3 |
|  1 | RIGID_AVG | NULL         |     3 |
|  2 | RIGID_AVG | NULL         |     3 |
+----+-----------+--------------+-------+
```

Comment: Just to state the obvious --- Depending on the population size, the number of permutations can quickly become ridiculous  +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Very true.

Answer (score 0):

You need all the permutations, so permutations table should be the first. Also, you need to join permutations with the corresponding data, not with anything from anywhere so why ON 1=1?

This will work:

```
SELECT A.Class,A.Name,X.Id,X.Factor_Value
FROM Permutations A
  JOIN Data X ON X.Class=A.Class and X.Name=A.name
```

Answer (score 0):

The big difference in what you want and what you got is almost the same as the difference between LEFT and RIGHT - literally.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A.ID,
    A.NAME,
    X.FACTOR_VALUE,
    A.CLASS
FROM Data X
RIGHT JOIN Permutations A
    ON A.ID = X.ID
    AND A.NAME = X.NAME
```